# Why does the OCaml pattern `zero -> zero` seem to match everything?

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

Here is a snippet of code from my book, and I'm not sure about how the matching works apparently because it seems the first case matches everything.  Here are the warnings Ocaml throws at me:

```
# let zero = 0;;
# let one = 1;;
# let rec fib i =
match i with
zero -> zero
| one -> one
| j -> fib (j - 2) + fib (j - 1);;
Characters 57-60:


Warning: this match case is unused.
Characters 74-75:
Warning: this match case is unused.
| one -> one
^^^
| j -> fib (j - 2) + fib (j - 1);; 
^
val fib : int -> int = <fun>
# fib 1;;
- : int = 1
# fib 2002;;
- : int = 2002
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a fairly common source of confusion.  In essence you want to think of patterns as being built from constants (like `0` and `1`) and identifiers that are *bound* by the pattern.

When an identifier shows up in a pattern, it matches anything at all, and binds the matched value to the identifier.  An identifier in a pattern does *not* refer to any previous value associated with the identifier.  So, indeed, your pattern will always match the first case and bind `zero` to the value of `i`.

You could imagine that you'd like to be able to give names to constant values, then use the names rather than the constants in a pattern.  However OCaml (like other FP languages) doesn't work that way.  One advantage (seems to me) is that it keeps things simple.

Comment: You can use the constants if you do something like `x where x == zero` (the precise syntax escapes me though)

Comment: You can use `when` to add an extra test to a match, but it doesn't change the meaning of the pattern.  It just applies an additional test.  If your pattern is just an identifier, this is just another way to write an `if` statement.  (Nothing wrong with `if` statements, that's what you'd probably use to test against named constants.)

Comment: Thank you Jeffrey, I found this pretty insightful.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that I'd add that if you rewrote the code to as follows, that it would work fine:

```
# let zero = 0;;
# let one = 1;;
# let rec fib i =
match i with
  0 -> zero
| 1 -> one
| j -> fib (j - 2) + fib (j - 1);;
```

The fundamental problem (as is fairly well explained in the other answer) is that you can create new local variables with the same name as global variables and that using any variable name on the left side of the match just creates a new local variable of that name and fills it with whatever is being matched.  Just as `j` is a new local variable which contains whatever is being matched, so is `zero`.  And the fact that it was previously declared in a larger scope is ignored by Ocaml (which is why you can happily write things like

```
let x = 1;;
let x = 2 in let x = 3 in x;;
```

which gives a result of 3.

Comment: This is a good point; the appearance of `zero` in the pattern creates a nested scope where `zero` is bound to a new value based on the match.  Most programming languages support nested scopes, not just OCaml.  The alternatives are generally worse; you probably don't want to limit the choices for local names depending on the names used elsewhere in the code.